# python logging: also show few lines of code above and below at that location

Tags: python, django, logging

I am working on a django project.

I have the following logging config in settings.py file

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(funcName)s() %(pathname)s[:%(lineno)s] %(name)s \n%(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    'loggers': {
        'custom_string': {
            'level': 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console']
        }
    }
}
```

We can see that verbose shows the `'%(levelname)s %(funcName)s() %(pathname)s[:%(lineno)s] %(name)s \n%(message)s`. It shows the filename, line number and function. I have to open that file and see that line number to get have a look at the code around the logger.

Now suppose i have the following code in views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

import logging
logger_custom_string = logging.getLogger("custom_string")


def test_log(request):


    from django import db
    user_set = User.objects.all()
    logger_custom_string("*********testing logging*********")
    for user in user_set:
        pass

    html = "<html><body>testing</body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

The logging will show in the console:

```
DEBUG test_log() ./django_log_project/views.py[:13] custom_string 
*********testing logging*********
```

What i want to see is

```
DEBUG test_log() ./django_log_project/views.py[:13] custom_string
Code:
11   from django import db
12   user_set = User.objects.all()
13   logger_custom_string("*********testing logging*********")
14   for user in user_set:
15       pass

output:
*********testing logging*********
```

This will show me the code line +2/3 and -2/3 lines from the line logger is called.

How can we do this.

Comment: For development, using `pdb` is highly recommended: https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/
You can add breakpoints and check the code around where the code fails etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below code in the settings.py in Django

I used custom formatter.  get the linenumber and filepath from the record and extract the top and bottom 3 lines in a list. Then add a new attribute , `codelines`, to record object and store the concatenated list into it.

```
class VerFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):

        lines=[]
        with open(record.pathname) as src:
            for index, line in enumerate(src.readlines(), start=1):
                if index == record.lineno:
                    lines.append('{:4d}* {}'.format(index, line))
                else:
                    lines.append('{:4d}: {}'.format(index, line))
        start=(record.lineno -1) - 3
        end=(record.lineno -1) + 3

        if record.lineno == len(lines):
            end = record.lineno-1
        if end > len(lines)-1:
            end = len(lines)-1
        if record.lineno -1 == 0:
            start = 0
        if start < 0:
            start = 0

        code = ''.join(lines[start:end])

        import pygments
        from pygments.lexers.python import Python3Lexer
        from pygments.formatters import TerminalTrueColorFormatter
        code = pygments.highlight(
            code,
            Python3Lexer(),
            #TerminalTrueColorFormatter(style='monokai')
            TerminalTrueColorFormatter()
        )

        record.codelines = code
        return super(VerFormatter, self).format(record)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            '()': VerFormatter,
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(funcName)s() %(pathname)s[:%(lineno)s] %(name)s \n%(codelines)s \n%(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'custom_string': {
            'level': 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console']
        }
    }
}
```